# Compile QT project from comman line

Tags: c++, qt

I don't like QtCreator, but I hope to use Qt libraries. I have installed Qt 5.15.0, and I'm wondering what cmd commands are needed to turn the code below into an executable, using qmake?

```
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QApplication>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc,argv);
    QPushButton hellobtn("Hello World!",0);
    hellobtn.resize(200,50);
    hellobtn.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Note that even creating an empty project in QtCreator is not preferable.
I thought it would be something like

```
qmake ...
mingw32-make ...
```

But when I first tried

```
qmake -project
```

it results in the error:

```
Error: Qt license file was not found!
Project ERROR: License check failed! Giving up ...
```

Comment: How did you install Qt?

Comment: You have to prepare `.pro` file ([tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-tutorial.html)). When you have `.pro` file for your project, run `qmake` which generates makefile based on `.pro`, then run the make (depends on compiler, for example `nmake` if VS is used).